# Suppose the sequences $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ converge to $a$ and $b$, respectively. Then the sequence $(a_{n}b_{n})_{n=m}^{\infty}$ converges to $ab$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, solution-verification

Suppose the sequences of real numbers $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ converge to $a$ and $b$, respectively.

Then the sequence $(a_{n}b_{n})_{n=m}^{\infty}$ converges to $ab$.

**MY ATTEMPT**

To start with, let us notice that
\begin{align*}
|a_{n}b_{n} - ab| & = |a_{n}b_{n} - a_{n}b + a_{n}b - ab|\\\\
& = |a_{n}(b_{n} - b) + b(a_{n} - a)|\\\\
& \leq |a_{n}||b_{n} - b| + |b||a_{n} - a| 
\end{align*}

Since $a_{n}$ converges, it is bounded. That is to say, $|a_{n}| \leq A$.

Hence we can rewrite the given relation as
\begin{align*}
|a_{n}b_{n} - ab| \leq A|b_{n} - b| + |b||a_{n} - a|
\end{align*}

Moreover, based on the convergence of $a_{n}$, for every $\varepsilon/2|b| > 0$, there exists a natural number $N\geq m$ such that
\begin{align*}
|a_{n} - a| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2|b|}
\end{align*}
whenever $n \geq N$.

Similarly, based on the convergence of $b_{n}$, for every $\varepsilon/2A > 0$, there exists a natural number $M\geq m$ such that
\begin{align*}
|b_{n} - b| \leq \frac{\varepsilon}{2A}
\end{align*}
whenever $n\geq M$. Finally, for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a natural $n_{0} = \max\{N,M\}$ such that
\begin{align*}
|a_{n}b_{n} - ab| \leq A|b_{n}-b| + |b||a_{n} - a| \leq A\times \frac{\varepsilon}{2A} + |b|\times\frac{\varepsilon}{2|b|} = \varepsilon
\end{align*}
whenever $n \geq n_{0}$, and we are done.

Could someone please double-check my reasoning? Any other solution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It is perfect...

Comment: Just a minox fix needed. State that $A>0$ and replace $|b|$ by $|b|+1$. Your proof can get in trouble if $b=0$ as $\epsilon /2|b|$ won't make sense.